# Записать буквы в обратном порядке

Tags: javascript

У меня есть такой вопрос. Так как я новичок ещё только на стадии изучения JavaScript. Не могли бы вы подсказать, что нужно сделать для того, чтобы буквы были записаны в обратном порядке? Спасибо!

Comment: Загони их в массив и переверни его. Аминь.

Comment: А как его перевернуть?

Comment: Вопрос на столько абстрактный, что на него можно ответить только так:
взять буквы и переставить! Думайте задавая вопросы. #Gerome прям в точку ответил.

Comment: Интересно, для чего это вам нужно?

Comment: Мож уже самбоди поменяет название вопроса?

Comment: Сразу предупреждаю, что не знаю JS, но интересно, почему самый очевидный способ (после нескольких минут разглядывания [мануала по JS строкам](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String))

    var str = "abcde", i, rev = "";
    for (i = str.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
       rev += str[i];
    }
    str = rev;

никто не предложил?

Comment: @avp а зачем, если reverse() [есть  в стандарте ecmascript](http://es5.javascript.ru/x15.4.html#x15.4.4.8)

Comment: @eicto, я же пишу, что JS не знаю. Набрал в гугле

    JS string

reverse в мануале от Mozilla Developers по контексту не нашел, почитал несколько минут, удивился что такую очевидную вещь никто не написал, вот и набил комментарий.

--

Понятно, что если бы строки в JS можно было бы модифицировать, то код

     for (i = 0, j = str.length - 1; i < j;) {
        var t = str[i];
        str[i++] = str[j];
        str[j--] = t;
     }

видимо был бы эффективней. Но, как говорится, на нет и суда нет.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse

я делаю так, в гугле забиваю "reverse mdn" :)

Comment: @eicto, а ведь в Ваших ссылках речь о массивах, а не строках. 

А этот вариант @knes уже давно описал.

Comment: жаль нельзя 

    Array.prototype.reverse.call("1234")

Comment: ну да, я просто подтверждаю, что это самый прямой путь это делать, вместо цикла, хотя можно конечно проверить на скорость ваш последний вариант.

Comment: @eicto, проверьте, если уже есть все необходимое окружение.

Но, мне кажется, основная проблема с "лишним" массивом будет в памяти, отсюда и время полезет. 

Т.е. проверять надо бы в "синтетическом" тесте, например, в цикле, где наряду с постоянно обновляемым реверсируемым str, становящимся мусором на каждой итерации, накапливается какой-то массив, ссылки на элементы которого не теряются.

Понятно, что эффект (на пустой машине) начнет проявляться при накоплении большого количества данных, интуитивно - после четверти PhysMem, считая "чистые" накапливаемые элементы.

Answer (score 24):

```
var str = 'abcd';

str = str.split("").reverse().join("");
```

Answer (score 4):

если не нужна поддержка юникодных суррогатов, то

```
function reverse(s){
    return s.split("").reverse().join("");
}
```

Если нужна, то посмотрите реализацию в [esrever](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/esrever/):

```
var regexSymbolWithCombiningMarks = /([\0-\u02FF\u0370-\u1AAF\u1B00-\u1DBF\u1E00-\u20CF\u2100-\uD7FF\uE000-\uFE1F\uFE30-\uFFFF]|[\uD800-\uDBFF][\uDC00-\uDFFF]|[\uD800-\uDBFF](?![\uDC00-\uDFFF])|(?:[^\uD800-\uDBFF]|^)[\uDC00-\uDFFF])([\u0300-\u036F\u1AB0-\u1AFF\u1DC0-\u1DFF\u20D0-\u20FF\uFE20-\uFE2F]+)/g;
var regexSurrogatePair = /([\uD800-\uDBFF])([\uDC00-\uDFFF])/g;

var reverse = function(string) {
    // Step 1: deal with combining marks and astral symbols (surrogate pairs)
    string = string
        // Swap symbols with their combining marks so the combining marks go first
        .replace(regexSymbolWithCombiningMarks, function($0, $1, $2) {
            // Reverse the combining marks so they will end up in the same order
            // later on (after another round of reversing)
            return reverse($2) + $1;
        })
        // Swap high and low surrogates so the low surrogates go first
        .replace(regexSurrogatePair, '$2$1');
    // Step 2: reverse the code units in the string
    var result = '';
    var index = string.length;
    while (index--) {
        result += string.charAt(index);
    }
    return result;
};
```

<sub>ответ честно взят с [enSO: How do you reverse a string in place in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16776621/1988244)</sub>

Answer (score 4):

Вариант через цикл (поддерживает Unicode):

```
var str = "→Привет, Мир!";
var strRev = ""; // строка в обратном порядке
for (i = str.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
  strRev += str[i];
}
```

Пояснение: начальное значение счётчика i, вычисляется как длина строки - 1, т.к. счёт длины начинается с 1, а доступ к элементам массива/строки начинается с 0.

Answer (score 0):

Шаг 1. Используем метод split(), чтобы получить массив из строки

Шаг 2. Используем метод reverse(), чтобы перевернуть элементы в полученном массиве

Шаг 3. Используем метод join(), чтобы соединить элементы массива

Шаг 4. Возвращаем перевернутую строку

```
function reverseString(str) {
  var newString = "";
  for (var i = str.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    newString += str[i];
  }
  console.log(newString);
}
reverseString('hello');
```

Comment: в приложенном блоке кода не реализован шаг 4, как впрочем и любой другой шаг из описания

Answer (score -1):

Кроме очевидных решение по типу `str.split('').reverse().join('')` и цикла `for` дейстующего в обратном порядке.

Можно использовать `reduceRight` (Метод, действующий как `reduce`, но справа на лево):

```js
var str = 'Hello, World!'

console.log(
  str
    .split('')
    .reduceRight((a, e) =>
      a + e
    , '')
)
```

Или же используя метод `replace`:

```js
var str = 'Hello, World!'

console.log(
  str
    .replace(
      /./g,
      (_, i, a) =>
        a[a.length - i - 1]
    )
)
```

Можно также использовать обычный цикл:

```js
var str = 'Hello, World!'
var _str = ''

for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
  let current = str[i]

  _str = current + _str
}

console.log(_str)
```

Answer (score -4):

```
        string s = "abcd";
        char[] v = s.ToArray();

        Array.Reverse(v);
        foreach (var c in v)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(c);
        }
        Console.Read();
```

Comment: это какой язык ? на javascript не похоже.

Comment: Похоже на C#

Comment: и за что + этому ответу ?